# How to read the varbinary (max) field value from SQL using VFP and Save it as pdf?

Tags: sql, pdf-generation, visual-foxpro, varbinarymax

I am connecting my vfp applcication with SQL server. One table having the varbinary field and I need to read the binary and convert that into pdf file . How I can do that ?

Comment: Find a PDF generation component that can be used from VFP. Don't forget to include all styles of component that VFP can use (eg. can it use COM?). But tool & component recommendations are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that the varbinary data itself is a PDF file (or any file)? If so just save the bytes you get to a file with a .PDF extension. ie:

Let's assume you have a table named "Files" in database "test" with fields like Id, FileExt and FileContent. FileExt holding the extension and FileContent is the file itself as varbinary(Max). You want to save all files to a folder named 'c:\temp\files':

```
Local handle, filename
handle = Sqlstringconnect("driver={Sql Server Native Client 11.0};server=.\SQLExpress;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=yes")

SQLExec(m.handle, 'Select * from [Files]', 'crsData')
SQLDisconnect(m.handle)

Select crsData
Scan
    fileName = Forcepath(Forceext(Ltrim(Str(crsData.Id)),Trim(crsData.FileExt)))
    Strtofile(crsData.FileContent, m.fileName, 'c:\temp\files')
Endscan
```